# Rendering: To draw-once or to re-draw? Would JOGL + Java2D + Java Swing be cumbersome?

Tags: java, android, swing, opengl-es, jogl

## 1) Re-Draw Vs Draw

Kind of a philosophical question, but... what is the "correct" or "accepted" way to render a game (2d, I understand how OGL perspecives work...) at different resolutions? Should I include separate sizes for my images (like Android APKs) and resize each object individually at draw on one canvas, or should I draw on a set-resolution drawing canvas, then resize that image onto another display canvas? I'm speaking generally, but, if you need me to be specific I'm using Java to build the engine.

Foreseeable benefits/issues:

```
#1) Resize at Draw
    + No additional drawing step
    + Sweet resolution
    - Possible math/physics/placement issues
    - Tons of math each step for scale
    - Lots of resources

#2) Resize at Render
    + No additional math; one step
    + One set of images; smaller res. package
    + One set canvas size (easier to do math/phys./placement)
    - Additional drawing step
    - Poor resolution =(
```

It would seem that #2 is the obvious choice because of the number of benefits vs issues, but... is it? Is there a standard way to resize 2D games?

## 2) JOGL + Java2D + Java Swing

Would it be cumbersome to use JOGL, Java2D, and Java Swing at the same time? Would it be worth it to do 2D or layouts in JOGL? Why or why not?

EDIT: Using a BufferedImage to draw on and rendering the BufferedImage to the size of the panel with respect to aspect ratio is incredibly inefficient in swing. Apparently it's better to draw immediately to the panel, while resizing each image/element individually. Not my first hypothesis...

EDIT 2: Silly me... just *scale and translate the graphics context* to the size of the adjusted resolution before any other operations. The performance boost is super-dooper awesome. THIS is the correct answer to the question. DRAW ONCE, to scale/translation. B)

Comment: Update: I ended up creating an BufferedImage from scratch, the size of the original resolution. I then drew that Image to the size of the display, once. B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your second question fully as I do not have much experience with JOGL or Java2D, but I don't see any reason for them to ever conflict or be cumbersome.

For your first question, I can definitely say that it depends. What's your target audience? Is your game memory intensive (Ever notice that many games have a high res/low res option)? Is this a game that will be available for vastly different screen sizes? If so you might want to provide 2-3 different "packages" of your assets, each scaled at a different size of the original (the largest one). The math to draw the images isn't as much as you think.

In addition:

If you build the game the right way, you wouldn't have to do much math at all. If you have some sort of `Camera` class that takes care of the viewing of your `GameWorld` then you simply have to scale the Camera's image instead of scaling each image independently.

Comment: Thank you for your input. My situation calls for extreme portability, so yes, it does make sense to be more resource intensive and less memory intensive. I can always exclude resources I don't need for specific platforms. The camera idea is good... maybe I can apply a sort of OGL perspective to my 2D perspective (-1 to 1) so that resolution becomes a non-issue. Good answer.